# Fill remainder of data set with nans in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a dataset which has some measurements for a given time period:

```
Jday = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-07-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Dat = rand(length(Jday),1);
```

I would now like to ensure that the data set covers the entire annual cycle for the given years under investigation (2010 and 2011 above). So, given that the data is measured hourly, how could I fill in the remaining times of the dataset with NaNs so that the final variable has a length equal to:

```
Jday = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
```

Where Dat, for example, between 2011-07-31 23:00 and 2011-12-31 23:00 would have NaNs?

Comment: Plain or garlic nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have R2013a, then you can also use `padarray()`:

```
B = padarray(A,padsize, NaN, 'post')
```

**NOTE**: if you are looking to take a union of two sets of dates, e.g. A and B, where without loss of generality A includes B, then you might have a_n <= b_n < a_n+1 in which case cannot simply pad the array, but you need to fill in with NaNs. This involves using `ismember()` and logical indexing, or even `accumarray()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the data only needs to be padded with `NaN` at the end, you can simply use:

```
pad_length = length(Jday) - length(Dat);
pad = ones(pad_length,1)*NaN;
Dat = [Dat;pad];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the array in-place to pad the end or munge it with `ismember`. Let's say you've got this.

```
AllDates = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Dates = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-07-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Dat = rand(length(Jday),1);
```

If you're just adding NaNs to the end (that is, you know Dates matches the first n points in AllDates), you can use simple assignment to non-existent elements to extend the array.

```
Dat(end+1:numel(AllDates)) = NaN;
```

If you need to identify holes at arbitrary locations, you can use `ismember` to drop your observations in to place in an array matching the larger set of dates.

```
Dat2 = NaN(size(AllDates));
[tf,ix] = ismember(Dates, AllDates);
if ~all(tf);  error('Some dates not in reference set');  end
Dat2(ix) = Dat;
```

BTW, you might want to use `numel` instead of `length`. It's more general; `length` may give you issues if you have 2-d arrays.